# PHP Curl авторизация. PrestaShop

Tags: php, curl, prestashop

Добрый день

Не получается сделать удаленную авторизацию через Curl. Сайт на движке PrestaShop. Может у кого есть какие то соображения?

Делаю так

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://example.com/index.php?controller=authentication';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'email'=>'email',
    'passwd'=>'passwd',
    'back'=>'my-account',
    'SubmitLogin'=>'1'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: вы хоть сам сайт укажите, и напишите что конкретно у вас не получается, что возвращает курл, может ошибку, какую, что ожидаете получить и т.п.

Comment: Сайт врядли поможет, а вот логи сервера и ответ курла очень помогут

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сохранять cookies:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
```

и использовать их в последующих запросах:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

так сайт будет понимать, что вы авторизовались (если POST-запрос ваш составлен верно, и авторизация прошла).

P.S. не забудте указать правильный путь к jar-файлу (должна быть возможность записи в него)